# Use DAX in powerbi to create a measure to calcul ate using two tables A and B (matching by id) applying a filter on table B

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables in powerbi

Table A

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Zelu |
| 2 | Bezeu |
| 3 | Aquino |

Table B

| ID_A | Class |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |

And a wish to calculate count of  names with class A
like
Zelu - 2
Bezeu - 1
Aquino - 0

There is away to use a DAX function to execute this job?
Thanks a lot!!!

Saulo

I tryed to use calculate function but i don´t know how to link tow tables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first establish a relationship between your tables that goes from `ID` in `Table A` to `ID_A` in `Table B`:

[image]

Then you simply add a measure:

```
Count = 
COUNTROWS ( 'Table B' ) + 0
```

Which you can use in a matrix visualization together with `'Table A'[Name]` and `'Table B'[Class]` to get your desired result:

[image]